# Are Scaffolding Nets are good options to put on my Trees to protect them from Birds and Squirrels?

Tags: protection

I was recently planning to buy some bird netting to protect my trees from Birds and Squirrels, but found a cheaper alternative , "Scaffolding Net"

I have never seen or touched one , in a close up situation. But they seem to be a good alternative to the bird nets.

Has anyone tried them for their trees ? 
Questions I have is mostly inclined towards 
.Do they allow enough Sunlight through to the Trees
. Do they work well for the use mentioned ?

Adding another question to this : 
Does the size of mesh matter in those nets ? As long as it allows enough air to pass through.

Comment: can you provide a link to the product?

Comment: I couldn't find a link to a product, but they look something like this ; http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00jSWtDKPJkioM/Drop-Cloth.jpg    You can also find many images on Google.

Comment: @kevinsky - google Scaffold Debris and Safety Netting, or one or the other.

Comment: @Bamboo yes, good suggestion, but the idea behind a good question is that it provides most of the details needed to answer it.  A few years from now that link might be dead and the context of what it is might be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you  pick one that's actually mesh - there's a wide range available, and some of them look almost solid, in other words, the mesh element is entirely covered by plastic, so it looks more like a roll of material or cloth, and that won't be great for covering trees. Other versions are actually mesh, often sold as scaffold safety netting rather than scaffold debris netting. You also need to pick one that has a mesh size which keeps out the size of bird you're aiming to keep off your fruit, assuming that's what you want it for. Something like Scaffnet would probably work - but it isn't cheap, I'd have thought garden mesh would be cheaper.

One site here in the UK says some of their netting is suitable for garden use, but doesn't tell you which, and I think they mean suitable for keeping out wind, insects and giving shade - in other words, over a support of some sort rather than directly in contact with plants. Types of netting include fire retardent, wind and rain barrier, debris prevention, safety.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am guessing the Scaffold nets would be more expensive than normal garden tree nets, but thats something that I will be looking at next. I couldn't find any online stores selling them in my country . I plan to use it for Birds and Squirrels mostly.